# Splitting chat records from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that is basically extracted from an instant messaging file using the code below:

```
with open(input('address here pls: '),'r') as f:
    f = f.readlines()
```

I am returned with a list of the elements such as

```
> ['=Start=','From: Me','To: You','Hey there','Howre u doing?','=End',
'=Start=','From: You','To: Me','Good!','How bout you?','=End',
]
```

I am trying to get everything in between Start and End, assign From and To as the table headers and get the message in between as the body.

End goal is to push it to a pandas dataframe.

Below is the results I am trying to get:

```
======================================
From|To |Message                     |
======================================
Me  |You|'Hey there Howre you doing?'|
You |Me |'Good! How bout you?'       |
```

Comment: "_I am trying to get_" - please show us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
L = ['=Start=','From: Me','To: You','Hey there','Howre u doing?','=End',
'=Start=','From: You','To: Me','Good!','How bout you?','=End',
]
#create df from L
df = pd.DataFrame({'Message': L})
#create groups by mask and cumulative sum
b = (df.Message == '=Start=').cumsum()

#extract text in From and To
df['From'] = df.Message.str.extract('From: (.*)', expand=False).ffill()
df['To'] = df.Message.str.extract('To: (.*)', expand=False).ffill()

#remove unnecessary rows
out = ['=Start=','=End','From:','To:']
df = df[~df.Message.str.contains('|'.join(out))]
#groupby by Series b and aggregate
df = df.groupby(b).agg({'Message': ' '.join, 'To': 'last', 'From': 'last'})
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
                    Message   To From
0  Hey there Howre u doing?  You   Me
1       Good! How bout you?   Me  You
```